# Bash: list files ordered by the number they contain

Tags: bash, sorting, filenames, ls

**Goal**

I have a series of files that have various names. Each file's name contain a unique integer number made of between 1 and 4 digits. I would like to order the files (by displaying their full name) but ordered by the number they contain.

**Example**

The files ..

```
Hello54.txt
piou2piou.txt
hap_1002_py.txt
JustAFile_78.txt
darwin2012.txt
```

.. should be listed as

```
piou2piou.txt
Hello54.txt
JustAFile_78.txt
hap_1002_py.txt
darwin2012.txt
```

Comment: Is there anything in particular that you're stuck with here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to sort by the numeric part. One approach might be to eliminate the non-numeric part and build an array. On the upside, bash has sparse arrays, so whatever order you *add* the members in, they will come out in the correct order. Pseudo code:

```
array[name_with_non_numerics_stripped]=name
print array
```

My quick and not careful implementation:

```
sortnum() {
    # Store the output in a sparse array to get implicit sorting
    local -a map
    local key
    # (REPLY is the default name `read` reads into.)
    local REPLY 
    while read -r; do
        # Substitution parameter expansion to nuke non-numeric chars
        key="${REPLY//[^0-9]}"
        # If key occurs more than once, you will lose a member.
        map[key]="$REPLY"
    done
    # Split output by newlines.
    local IFS=$'\n'
    echo "${map[*]}"
}
```

If you have two members with the same "numeric" value, only the last one will be printed. @BenjaminW suggested appending such entries together with a newline. Something like…

```
[[ ${map[key]} ]] && map[key]+=$'\n'
map[key]+="$REPLY"
```

…in place of the `map[key]="$REPLY"` above.

Comment: Fix for duplicates: if an entry is non-empty, append `\n$REPLY` to existing entry? Needs `echo -e` in the last statement.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I'm generally leery of introducing another delimiter into bash arrays (making them multidimensional), but in this case I suppose that's "good enough".